# Do order array with years php

Tags: php

I have a array with:

```
$strings = ['n/a', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years', '1 year'];
```

How I can order years? I need get result:

```
$strings = ['n/a', '1 year', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years'];
```

`sort` function is not work in this cause. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: `'n/a'` will be always at first place?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Yep

Comment: try [`natsort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) but not sure where that would put `n/a`

Comment: What about if you have `11 year` in the list - should that be last or after `1 year`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

$strings = ['n/a', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years', '1 year'];

// remove first value from array and save it in a variable
$first_val = array_shift($strings);

//sort array based on string comparison
usort($strings, "strcmp");

//add removed value again at first position of the array
array_unshift($strings,$first_val);

//print array to see everything fine or not?
print_r($strings);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/4TcBi

Note:- In case `n/a` is not the first value then do like below:

https://3v4l.org/FbWvV

Answer (score 1):

May be it will help you:

```
sort($strings, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Comment: n/a on last position, I need on first position.

Comment: you can remove it, then sort array and then add `n/a` like that:
`$sortedArr = $firstElem + $sortedArr;`

Answer (score 1):

Would it can help you

```php
$strings = ['n/a', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years', '1 year'];

usort($strings, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a == 'n/a') {
      return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$strings =  ['n/a', '1 year', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years'];
$numbers = array();
$albhabets = array();
foreach($strings as $v)
{

  if(is_numeric($v[0]))
    {
      array_push($numbers,$v);
    }else
    {
      array_push($albhabets,$v);
    }  
}
sort($numbers);
sort($albhabets);

print_r(array_merge($albhabets,$numbers));
```